# how do I change the position of my image with coordinate ranges in vba

Tags: vba, coordinates, userform, chess

I'm trying to program a Chess-Game in VBA. I'd like to change the position of the figures with mousemove. I can already move them but It would be great if I could release the figure and the figure so jumped into the middle of the field.

I have no Idea how do solve the Problem

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I tried to work with select case and coordinates, but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Best case scenario - use the macro recorder. Copy the figure and paste it somewhere.

See the code. Then make sure that it works, only in the given range of the chessboard. Then make an event like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:H8")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Target.Address

End Sub
```

And try to build the recorded code in `Target.Address`. The event is for the right click of the mouse. It should be put in the Worksheet part of the VBEditor.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But I have the assignment to drag and drop the figures....

Comment: @Firelively - try to do it with rightclick, using the code above and understanding the logic. From there to drag and drop it is only one step.